# What does the choosing consistency type "Ask Whose Job It Is" guidance mean?

Tags: domain-driven-design, consistency, aggregateroot

When discussing how to decide whether transactional or eventual consistency should be used in Part II of [Vaughn Vernon's Effective Aggregate Design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/), he states

> When examining the use case (or story), ask whether it's the job of
>   the user executing the use case to make the data consistent. If it is,
>   try to make it transactionally consistent, but only by adhering to the
>   other rules of aggregate. If it is another user's job, or the job of
>   the system, allow it to be eventually consistent.

I don't follow. Does anyone have a good example of applying this rule of thumb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I get it :

- `MovePiece()` on `ChessBoard` aggregate => user's responsibility. The action should all take place in one transaction contained within the `ChessBoard` boundary.
- `DecideGameOver()` on `ChessGame` aggregate => system's responsibility.

  Some handler subscribes to `ChessBoard`'s `PieceMoved` events and
  delegates to the `ChessGame` aggregate for it to decide if the game is
  over. We can tolerate a delay between the final move being made on
  the Board and when the Game aggregate is updated - it's eventual
  consistency.

It's not a hard and fast rule though, more of an indicator generalized from observation of dozens of systems.

Comment: Thank you. I get your point but I think chess is an awkward example since it can reasonably be modeled as one large aggregate (everything is turn based, so synchronous with only two users and no multi-tenancy). I think a more useful example would be something like a website visitor filling out a registration form and their account being activated.

Comment: Good point. I chose chess to make it simpler but the real project I was initially thinking about is a multiplayer game. Anyway, I'd be interested to see other answers. As I said, it's just my interpretation of the rule.